# Allocate contracts equally across people?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 tables like the below in SQL server..

```
ContractID      StartDate      ContractManagerID
222            01 jan 2023         NULL
223            02 jan 2023         NULL
225            02 jan 2023         NULL
243            05 jan 2023         NULL
282            07 jan 2023         NULL
290            08 jan 2023         NULL
```

I then have a "contract manager" table like the below..

```
ContractManagerID     Name         
1                     John               
2                     Julie              
3                     Andrew
```

I am trying to write some code that will look at how many ContractIDs have a NULL contract manager ID, and then allocate them evenly across the contract managers in table 2.

So in this case, there are 6 accounts that need allocating but 3 account managers.. so I want to loop through the account managers (ordered by contract manager id) to allocate the contract manager id to the contractmanagerid column on the first table until all accounts have been assigned.

Any ideas on the best way to achieve this?

Comment: If there are non-null Contract Manager IDs in the same table, does that affect things? I.e. if there's a mix of null and non-null rows in the table, are we trying to just balance new allocations or balance all allocations including existing ones?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with one update using the modulo of row_number() over contracts and count(*) over managers

Sorry I can't verify with SQL server 2012

```
CREATE TABLE Contracts
    ([ContractID] int, [StartDate] datetime, [ContractManagerID] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO Contracts
    ([ContractID], [StartDate], [ContractManagerID])
VALUES
    (222, '2023-01-01 01:00:00', NULL),
    (223, '2023-01-02 01:00:00', NULL),
    (225, '2023-01-02 01:00:00', NULL),
    (243, '2023-01-05 01:00:00', NULL),
    (282, '2023-01-07 01:00:00', NULL),
    (290, '2023-01-08 01:00:00', NULL)
;



CREATE TABLE ContractManagers
    ([ContractManagerID] int, [Name] varchar(6))
;
    
INSERT INTO ContractManagers
    ([ContractManagerID], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 'John'),
    (2, 'Julie'),
    (3, 'Andrew')
;
```

```
update c set ContractManagerID = d.ContractManagerID
from Contracts c
inner join (
  select a.Contractid, b. ContractManagerID from (
    select
      ContractID,
      (row_number() over(order by ContractID) - 1) % (select count(*) from ContractManagers)
      + 1 as ContractManagerNumber
    from Contracts
    where ContractManagerID is null
  ) a inner join (
    select
      ContractManagerID,
      row_number() over(order by ContractManagerID) as ContractManagerNumber
    from ContractManagers
  ) b on b.ContractManagerNumber = a.ContractManagerNumber
) d on d.Contractid = c.Contractid;

select * from Contracts
```

| ContractID | StartDate | ContractManagerID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 222 | 2023-01-01 01:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 223 | 2023-01-02 01:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 225 | 2023-01-02 01:00:00.000 | 3 |
| 243 | 2023-01-05 01:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 282 | 2023-01-07 01:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 290 | 2023-01-08 01:00:00.000 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cuuzYl5w)

Comment: One last join on contracts is not needed, you can just update a from a join b. https://dbfiddle.uk/z4p6HKiy

Either way it is a good solution

Comment: Agree, nice solution and about the join. It works fine in SQL Server 2012 too

Comment: @NenadZivkovic Or without the subquery using another window function https://dbfiddle.uk/cY8cnk1g